# How to convert working bash script to ksh script

Tags: regex, bash, ksh

I am unfamiliar with ksh scripting and I want to convert this to a working ksh script.

```
egrep "^[^#;]" /etc/security/user | 
while read x; 
do 
if [[ $x == '^\S+:' ]]; then 
section=$x; 
fi; 
if [[ $section == 'nobody:' ]]; then 
echo $x; 
fi; 
done
```

The contents of /etc/security/user are as follows:

```
sys:
        admin = true
        expires = 0101000070
        login = false
        rlogin = false
adm:
        admin = true
        login = false
        rlogin = false
nobody:
        admin = true
        expires = 0101000070
        login = false
        rlogin = false
invscout:
        admin = true
```

My goal is to be able to specify which user I would like to grab the parameters from and have it echo just that user's parameters. For example if I specify "nobody" in the command the shell should output:

```
    admin = true
    expires = 0101000070
    login = false
    rlogin = false
```

I understand ksh does not support pattern matching regular expression the same as bash does but am having trouble successfully converting the command. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. The command without and spaces is as follows:

`grep "^[^#;]" /etc/security/user | while read x; do if [[ $x =~ '^\S+:' ]]; then section=$x; fi; if [[ $section == 'nobody' ]]; then echo $x; fi; done`

Comment: Don't use backticks for multi-line code segments; they're for less-than-a-line snippets only.

Comment: BTW, `[[ $string =~ $re ]]` is actually **completely legal** in ksh. On the other hand, `\S` is a PCRE extension, not guaranteed to work in ERE (and thus, not guaranteed to work in bash).

Comment: well, completely legal in proper David Korn ksh93. There are lots of different versions of ksh (and don't get me started on the multitude of awful, slow, incompatible clones). Specifying the exact shell and version would be helpful.

Comment: BTW, "I need someone to do X for me" generally does not a good StackOverflow question make. We're here to help with problems you run into while trying to write code yourself, not to build solutions on your behalf.

Comment: To be clear, btw, `[[ $x == '^\S+:' ]]` was invalid -- never-ever-worked level invalid -- in bash too; it checks whether your string is exactly `^\S+:`, *not* checking whether your string matches a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems aren't specific to ksh at all. The following is perfectly legal in ksh (version 93u+ 2012-08-01), and is *also* best-practices code in bash (or at least close to it; one might move the `grep` into a process substitution as an enhancement that would add value in both shells).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
section_re='^[^[:space:]]+:'
grep -v '^[#;]' /etc/security/user |
  while IFS= read -r x; do
    if [[ $x =~ $section_re ]]; then
      section=$x
    fi
    if [[ $section = 'nobody:' ]]; then
      echo "$x"
    fi
  done
```

- `==` is not a POSIX-standardized argument to `test` for string comparison. Use `=` instead, even on non-POSIX shells, to ensure good habits (that will transfer to POSIX platforms).
- `=` and `==` do not perform regex tests; the operator for that is `=~`.
- The right-hand argument of `=~` **must be unquoted** to prevent it from being treated as literal. Putting the regex in a variable, and expanding that variable unquoted, is the best-practices portable mechanism to do this.
- `\S` is not valid in POSIX Extended Regular Expressions, which is the only syntax guaranteed to be supported on the right-hand side of `=~` in either ksh *or* bash.
- Quote all expansions. `echo "$x"`, not `echo $x`.
- Use the `-r` argument to `read` unless you explicitly want the behavior it suppresses (removing literal backslashes from input unless paired, honoring them as making `read` consume multiple lines if such a backslash was the last character).
- Clear `IFS` when invoking `read` (thus, use `IFS= read`) unless you explicitly want the behavior of trimming leading and trailing whitespace; *or* if you need `IFS` to be used to distinguish boundaries between multiple fields being concurrently read.

Output of the above, when run with ksh93 and your provided sample input file, is:

```
nobody:
        admin = true
        expires = 0101000070
        login = false
        rlogin = false
```

(Including `nobody:` in output is also expected, for reasons that are obvious if one reads the code; put a `continue` immediately following after `section=$x`, inside the same `if`, if *that's* undesired).

In the future, please run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.